# Uber API doesn't allow request from localhost

Tags: curl, cors, postman, uber-api

When I use the Uber API, with localhost I receive the following error:

... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

So maybe I made an error. To test, I tried the url in Postman, but everything works as expected; I receive the expected JSON data. I also tried with curl. It works as expected.

I am sending my server token and I've adjusted my headers. No luck.

Previous SO answers hinted at this quote: "The Uber API implements the OAuth 2.0 standard for secure authentication and
authorization. All communication with our servers must be over SSL (https://)."

Does this mean I have to use https:// ? I haven't had issues with any other APIs before this.

Comment: What happens when you use `https://` instead, as you suggest here?

Comment: Can't get it setup. I need a certificate. Webpack's dev server certificate expired. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Get a certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and install it on your webserver of choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to use https. Some apis require it, others will take either depending on the receiving application.