# Not able to access uber api from localhost

Tags: uber-api

I set up localhost on my dashboard but
I'm getting this error with the origin not allowing it:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.7752315&start_longitude=-122.418075&end_latitude=37.7752415&end_longitude=-122.518075 …. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're running an unsecured local server. Any API call to the Uber API should use TSL (HTTPS). Based on your error message, you seem to make calls from http://. Could you try to enable TSL in your local server configuration and try again?

You can also take a look at this answer here: [Uber API doesn't allow request from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269501/uber-api-doesnt-allow-request-from-localhost)